# MAMP環境でのホストの指定について

Tags: mamp

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost:8888","root","root","hoge");
```

MAMP環境にてデータベースアクセスする際、PHPのコードは上記記述で接続できましたが、
MAMPのポート設定を確認したらApacheが8888でMySQLが8889でした。
なぜ8889ではなく8888となるのでしょうか。

なおMAMPの設定は、ドキュメントルートをiCloud上のフォルダに設定している以外はデフォルトから変えていません。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「PHPのコードは上記記述で接続できました」を再確認されてはいかがでしょうか。実際にSELECT文が動くか、とか。

Comment: ご指導ありがとうございます。ご指摘の点につきましては、全く疑っていないポイントでしたので、改めてもう一度色々と試してみようと思います。